# How to create Select statement which searches in whole table instead of single column?

Tags: sql

I have 5 columns in a database table.

Column names are: English, French, German, Spanish, Russian.

I want to create select statement which searches for a word in the whole table (including all columns) instead of just one column, e.g.:

```
select * from language
where English = "Parrot"
```

The query above only searches "English" column for word "Parrot".

I want a select statement which searches for "Parrot" in all columns.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the `OR` (I just fall in love with `find_in_set`)

```
select 
find_in_set('Parrot', 
  concat(English, ',', French, ',', German, ',', Spanish, ',', Russian)
) as pos
from language
having pos<>0
```

And the column `pos` can indicate which language match the search term.

However, normalize is the better solution

Answer (score 1):

You need unpivot the table and then do a regular where-search

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll get anything better than plain `or`

```
Select * from language where English = "Parrot" or French = "Parrot" or German = "Parrot"
```

Otherwise, you could move individual translations into a separate table. So, one row in `language` will have not five strictly set columns, but five (or any other number) associated rows in a `language_word` table.

Answer (score 0):

The simples solution would be:

```
Select * from language where English = "Parrot"
OR French = "Parrot"
OR German = "Parrot"
OR Spanish = "Parrot"
OR Russian = "Parrot"
```

This solution may lack scalability. If you are planning to expand table by adding new columns you write your own function to perform the searching.

[Here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm) is a sample stored procedure that searches whole database for a specified keyword, it might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL isn't AFAIK very good at optimizing ORs, and with that approach your solution won't be very easy to maintain if you decide to add new languages in the future.

I'd definitely change the table structure to a normalized one.